# Python: Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'table_data' when trying to run file

Tags: python, conda, importerror

My workspace

```
work_folder
---index.py
---__init__.py
---apps
   |___table.py
   |___table_data.py
   |_____init__.py
```

I have imported `table.py` into `index.py` and it's not returnig any errors. But when when i import `table_data.py` into `table.py` and run `index.py` it's showing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'table_data'` .

When i run `table.py` individually there's no error.

I am inside a conda virtual environment.

Comment: Can you share the import statement you have used as well

Comment: ``from apps import table`` -index.py1.   
``from table_data import table_df``-table.py.
Error is occurring only when i run ``index.py``. running ``table.py`` returns no errors

Comment: As you are running your code from the root directory so it's trying to find the file in the root directory only.